# How to turn off the double-click/zoom behaviour of a leaflet map?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, r-leaflet, tmap

I am building a shiny app that contains a leaflet map object and the following functionality.
Basically, I want to single-click on the map, grab the coordinates of the clicked spot, use `sf` to filter my data using these coordinates, and then display the filtered data as table in another widget.
Here is my issue now:

- When I click once on the map, only the tooltip is shown.
- When I double-click, my functionality works but the maps zooms in
- Alternatively, I can click once (the tooltip comes up) and then click the second time to show my table.

Is there a way I can prevent this? (i.e. not show the tooltip when I single-click, or prevent the map from zooming in when I double-click)

Here is a reproducible example of my app:
Input files are found in this [Google Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YeSh-8YWyms5Z5Xfq-F0ESNgyhx0_Y3o)

```r
# install required packages in they are not already installed
if(!"remotes" %in% installed.packages()){
  install.packages("remotes")
}
# list my required packages
required_pkgs = c("magrittr", "dplyr", "shiny", "bslib", "leaflet", "sf", "tmap", "viridis")

# Get the missing required packages and install them
missing_pkgs <- setdiff(required_pkgs, installed.packages()[, "Package"])
if(length(missing_pkgs) != 0){
  remotes::install_cran(missing_pkgs)
}

# load the libraries of my required packages
lapply(required_pkgs, require, character.only = T)
#> Loading required package: magrittr
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> Loading required package: shiny
#> Loading required package: bslib
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'bslib'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     page
#> Loading required package: leaflet
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
#> Loading required package: tmap
#> Breaking News: tmap 3.x is retiring. Please test v4, e.g. with
#> remotes::install_github('r-tmap/tmap')
#> Loading required package: viridis
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
#> [[1]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] TRUE

# Load data
district <- readRDS("district.RDS")
sectors <- readRDS("sectors.RDS")
locations <- readRDS("locations.RDS")

# Create the map with shiny
#=========================
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My test map title"),
  fluidRow(
      column(4,
            card(
              id = "detailsCard",
              style = "height: 60vh;",
              full_screen = FALSE,
              card_header("Details at click point"),
              card_body(
                tableOutput("details")
                )
            )
        ),
      column(8,
      card(
        id = "mapCard",
        style = "height: 100vh;",
        full_screen = TRUE,
        card_header("Map"),
        card_body(
          leafletOutput("map")
        )
      )
   )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # create the tmap object
    tmap_object <- tm_shape(sectors) +
      tm_borders() +
      tm_fill(col = "number_of_clients",
              title = "number of clients",
              style = "jenks", 
              palette = cividis(6),
              id = "sector", # to specify which column to use for tooltips
              alpha = .6) + 
      tm_view(bbox = st_bbox(district))  # Set the initial extent to fit the AoI layer
    
    # convert the tmap object to a leaflet map 
    tmap_leaflet(tmap_object) 
  })
  
  
  # Map click logic
  observe({
    # clear previous click
    leaflet::leafletProxy("map") |>
      leaflet::clearMarkers()
    
    # get new click
    click <- input$map_click
    
    # add click to map
    leaflet::leafletProxy("map") |>
      leaflet::addMarkers(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat)
  }, priority = 100) |>
    shiny::bindEvent(input$map_click)
  
  # pt
  pt <- shiny::reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$map_click$lat)) {
      pt <- sf::st_point(
        c(
          input$map_click$lng,
          input$map_click$lat
        )
      ) |>
        sf::st_sfc(crs = 4326) |>
        sf::st_as_sf() |>
        sf::st_transform(st_crs(district))
      
      return(pt)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  # intersects
  intersects <- shiny::reactive({
    if (!is.null(pt())) {
      sectors %>% st_filter(pt(), .predicate = st_intersects) 
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  # table
  output$details <- shiny::renderTable({
    if (is.null(intersects())) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    if (nrow(intersects()) > 0) {
      locations %>% st_filter(intersects(), .predicate = st_intersects) %>% st_drop_geometry()
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2024-02-21 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Rwanda.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Rwanda.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_Rwanda.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_Rwanda.utf8    
#> 
#> time zone: Africa/Kigali
#> tzcode source: internal
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] viridis_0.6.5     viridisLite_0.4.2 tmap_3.3-4        sf_1.0-15        
#> [5] leaflet_2.2.1     bslib_0.6.1       shiny_1.8.0       dplyr_1.1.4      
#> [9] magrittr_2.0.3   
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] gtable_0.3.4            ggplot2_3.4.4           xfun_0.42              
#>  [4] raster_3.6-26           htmlwidgets_1.6.4       lattice_0.21-9         
#>  [7] leaflet.providers_2.0.0 vctrs_0.6.5             tools_4.3.2            
#> [10] crosstalk_1.2.1         generics_0.1.3          parallel_4.3.2         
#> [13] tibble_3.2.1            proxy_0.4-27            fansi_1.0.6            
#> [16] pkgconfig_2.0.3         KernSmooth_2.23-22      RColorBrewer_1.1-3     
#> [19] lifecycle_1.0.4         compiler_4.3.2          munsell_0.5.0          
#> [22] terra_1.7-71            codetools_0.2-19        leafsync_0.1.0         
#> [25] httpuv_1.6.14           stars_0.6-4             htmltools_0.5.7        
#> [28] class_7.3-22            sass_0.4.8              yaml_2.3.8             
#> [31] later_1.3.2             pillar_1.9.0            jquerylib_0.1.4        
#> [34] ellipsis_0.3.2          classInt_0.4-10         cachem_1.0.8           
#> [37] lwgeom_0.2-13           abind_1.4-5             mime_0.12              
#> [40] tidyselect_1.2.0        digest_0.6.34           fastmap_1.1.1          
#> [43] grid_4.3.2              colorspace_2.1-0        cli_3.6.2              
#> [46] base64enc_0.1-3         dichromat_2.0-0.1       XML_3.99-0.16.1        
#> [49] utf8_1.2.4              leafem_0.2.3            e1071_1.7-14           
#> [52] withr_3.0.0             scales_1.3.0            promises_1.2.1         
#> [55] sp_2.1-3                rmarkdown_2.25          gridExtra_2.3          
#> [58] png_0.1-8               memoise_2.0.1           evaluate_0.23          
#> [61] knitr_1.45              tmaptools_3.1-1         rlang_1.1.3            
#> [64] Rcpp_1.0.12             xtable_1.8-4            glue_1.7.0             
#> [67] DBI_1.2.1               reprex_2.1.0            rstudioapi_0.15.0      
#> [70] jsonlite_1.8.8          R6_2.5.1                fs_1.6.3               
#> [73] units_0.8-5
```

Comment: Could you share the UI as well? And the `library` calls please.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have added a simple reproducible example of my app.